# Relacionar arquivos de um diretório que iniciam com determinado texto

Tags: php, arquivo, diretório

Estou trabalhando no desenvolvimento de uma página em html/PHP na qual o objetivo é realizar a busca de informações sobre determinados processos.

Para cada processo abrangido pelo filtro de pesquisa a página exibe um conjunto de informações.

Meu objetivo é relacionar arquivos de um diretório específico que possuem relação aos processos filtrados. Todos os arquivos ficam relacionados no mesmo diretório sendo que cada arquivo tem seu nome iniciado com o ano e o número do processo (nesse formato: `yyyy_p_resto-do-nome.zip`, onde `yyyy` é o ano e `p` é o número do processo).

Basicamente, preciso de um exemplo de código que me permita relacionar os arquivos para download na página com base nesse inicio de nome, tendo em mente que trabalho com variáveis no php para o ano e o número do processo desejado.
Pra tentar facilitar mais a compreensão, suponhamos que do universo de arquivos que eu tenho no diretório, eu queira relacionar todos os que iniciam com "`2018_10_`" para exibir na página e fazer seu download.

Espero que tenha sido claro o suficiente. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar `glob()`, ficando assim:

```
$ano = 2018;
$mes = 10;
$pasta = 'foo/bar/downloads';

foreach (glob($pasta . '/' . $ano . '_' . $mes . '_*.zip') as $arquivo) {
    echo 'Arquivo:', $arquivo, '<br>';
}
```

Isso `$ano . '_' . $mes . '_*.zip'` resultaria nisto `2018_10_*.zip'`, sendo o `*` o caractere curinga, ou seja entre o `2018_10_` e o `.zip` pode conter qualquer coisa.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certinho

Answer (score 0):

Com  [**scandir()**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.scandir.php) - Liste os arquivos que estão no caminho especificado e dentro do `foreach` coloque uma condicional para exibir somente os que possuem a string especificada no nomes.

```
$string = '2018_10_';

$files = scandir('diretorio/');
foreach($files as $file) {
    if (strpos($file, $string) !== false) {
        echo $file;
        /***** disponibiliza para download qualquer tipo de arquivo.
         Se forem .zip não há necessidade do atributo download 
        ****************/
        echo "<a href=\"diretorio/". $file."\" download>". $file."</a>";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Ou use  [**directoryIterator**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) que fornece uma interface simples para visualização de conteúdo de diretórios de arquivos

```
$dir=new DirectoryIterator("diretorio/");
foreach ($dir as $file) {
    if (strpos($file,"2018_10_")!== false) {
      echo $file . "<br>\n";
    }
}
```